# Delete log file if it is empty after being closed

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a library function that launches a generic background process and logs it.

```
def LaunchAndLog(cmd):
    cmd_args = cmd.split() # Split arguments into array
    logfile = cmd_args[0] + '.log'
    with open(logfile,'w') as log:
        return subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=log,stderr=log)
```

**Main question:** Is it possible to revise this function so that upon the log file being closed, *if it is empty* it is deleted automatically?

**Note:** I want a solution where I can call this function and forget it. I don't want to have to remember to call a cleanup function every time after the job ends.

**(Rejected?) Idea:** I can use `threading` to launch a separate thread that monitors the process and/or log file, but this seems more complicated than necessary.

**Note**: Must work in Python 2.7, but I'm also interested in a Python 3 solution, if it's simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing the concept, and only create the file when you're ready to write. Create your own class to handle the file object:

```
class MyFile():
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __init__(self, path):
        ''' store the path, but don't actually open the file '''
        self.path = path
        self.file_object = None

    def write(self, s):
        ''' you open the file here, just before writing '''
        if not self.file_object:
            self.file_object = open(self.path, 'w')
        self.file_object.write(self, s)

    def close(self):
        ''' close the file '''
        if self.file_object:
            self.file_object.close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.close()
```

Then your `with` statement becomes this:

```
with MyFile(logfile) as log:
```

---

*Proposed but rejected edit from supergra manually incorporated*

Comment: This does not quite work as written. It needs an `__enter__` function and the `__exit__` function needs to accept 4 arguments, not 1. See here for an edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3772114 which was helpfully rejected by the SO goons.

Comment: Sorry, one more problem I've run into. You need to define a `fileno()` function in the class. I did this: `def fileno(self): if self.file_object: return self.file_object.fileno() else: return None`. Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: @user2066480, `__exit__()` calls `close()`. can't edit that out