# Don't save empty file

Tags: python

I create a new text file with `f = open('file.txt', 'w')`. Then, as I go about to get stuff to write on it, there is a problem and I need to exit without actually writing anything.

However, the file is still created, but empty. Is there a way to keep the file from being saved in case nothing is going to be written on it, or do I have to explicitly delete it in case something goes wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete log file if it is empty after being closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028526/delete-log-file-if-it-is-empty-after-being-closed)

Comment: The answer in the linked dupe is precisely the same I'd give here, even if this question isn't specifically about saving log files

Comment: Okay, how do I close this since the solution can be found elsewhere?

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's a good question, and will help others find the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `atexit` to simulate this behavior, but there's probably a Better Way out there somewhere.

```
import atexit

def safety_trigger():
    try:
        os.remove(FILENAME)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

atexit.register(safety_trigger)

with open(FILENAME,'w') as f:
    # do your
    # file operations
    atexit.unregister(safety_trigger)
```

This way when your script starts, you set it to automatically delete `FILENAME` when it ends.  Once you're done writing to the file, you tell your script NOT to automatically delete `FILENAME` when it ends.

Comment: +1 for coming up with a solution that would require minimal changes to existing code. This seems more elegant to me than using a wrapper class or storing output in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply prepare the information for writing first and only perform the saving and such if it makes it through preparation without a hitch.

```
info_to_write = ""
try:

    info_to_write += "something!"
    # etc...

    if something_went_wrong:
        raise Exception
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(info_to_write)
catch:
    print "Nothing written, no file created"
```