# python only create log file if logged something

Tags: python

Is there a way to only create log file if something got logged?  My program seems to create the log file even if nothing was logged.

```
import logging

logfilePath = "mylog.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfilePath, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

myfunc1thatmightuseslog()
myfunc2thatmightuseslog()
```

Comment: Where are you using the actual log

Comment: I am using in different functions but I want to set up the log but not create file until I use it

Comment: Why though? A log should be a record of a run; if nothing occurred you might want to know that.

Comment: because if I see the file I can know something is wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete log file if it is empty after being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028526/delete-log-file-if-it-is-empty-after-being-closed)

Comment: @EXODIA somewhat but not really as he's not using logging library

Comment: There is not such option to do with basicConfig and hence a manual class or what you say context manager needs to be created as mentioned in the suggested answer

Answer (score 1):

File handlers and subclasses all accept a `delay` keyword ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler)):

```
class logging.FileHandler(filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False, errors=None)
```

> Returns a new instance of the `FileHandler` class. The specified file is opened and used as the stream for logging. If mode is not specified, `'a'` is used. If *encoding* is not `None`, it is used to open the file with that encoding. **If *delay* is true, then file opening is deferred until the first call to `emit()`**. By default, the file grows indefinitely. If *errors* is specified, it’s used to determine how encoding errors are handled.

However, this option is not plumbed through to `basicConfig`, so it will always take the default value `False` in that case. Instead of using the `basicConfig` convenience, you'll want to configure logging explicitly in order to use this feature.